# Regarding the factorization $a^2+3b^2 = cd$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, factoring, quadratic-forms

Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive integers, with $\gcd(c,d)=1$, such that
$$a^2+3b^2=cd.$$
By well-known classical results, we have that $c$ and $d$ are both of the form $u^2+3v^2$.

**QUESTION:** Is it valid to claim that that *there exists at least one representation*
\begin{align}
    (c,d) = (p^2+3q^2,\ r^2+3s^2)
\end{align}
in [not necessarily positive] integers $p,q,r,s$ such that
\begin{align}
    (a,b) &= (pr+3qs,\ ps-qr) &\text{or}&& (a,b) &= (pr-3qs,\ ps+qr),
\end{align}
or does this commit some sort of unique factorization error?

Comment: You can set different views on multipliers.  $$a^2+3b^2=cd$$  For example like this. $$a=p^2+2(k+s)p+ks$$  $$b=p^2-ks$$  $$c=2(p^2+kp+k^2)$$  $$d=2(p^2+sp+s^2)$$  It is not clear that it is necessary in this matter? What kind of ideas?

Comment: If $${a}^{2}+{b}^{2}\,q=c\,d$$

$$a={k}_{1}\,p\,t+{p}_{1}\,k\,t+2\,{p}_{1}\,n\,p+2\,{k}_{1}\,k\,m$$

$$q=4\,m\,n-{t}^{2}$$

$$b={k}_{1}\,p-{p}_{1}\,k$$

$$c\,d=4\,\left( {k}_{1}\,{p}_{1}\,t+{p}_{1}^{2}\,n+{k}_{1}^{2}\,m\right) \,\left( k\,p\,t+n\,{p}^{2}+{k}^{2}\,m\right)$$

or

$$a={k}_{1}\,k\,{t}^{2}+{k}_{1}\,n\,p\,t+{p}_{1}\,k\,n\,t+2\,{p}_{1}\,{n}^{2}\,p-2\,{k}_{1}\,k\,m\,n$$

$$q=4\,m\,n-{t}^{2}$$

$$b={k}_{1}\,\left( k\,t+n\,p\right) +{p}_{1}\,k\,n$$

$$c\,d=4\,{n}^{2}\,\left( {k}_{1}\,{p}_{1}\,t+{p}_{1}^{2}\,n+{k}_{1}^{2}\,m\right) \,\left( k\,p\,t+n\,{p}^{2}+{k}^{2}\,m\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, this is Theorem 69 on page 91 of Dickson, *Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* (1929). You have made it easier by demanding $c,d$ coprime. The reason this matters is that Dickson's forms need not be primitive, so $2x^2 + 2 xy + 2 y^2$ might come up

[image]